# blender 2.79 render pixelated & now creates a file without an extension

Tags: blender-2.76

I have been asked to edit a few videos for a group which is outside of my developer skill set. I have settled upon Blender version 2.79 and have managed to make all of the changes and have the finished item that I am happy with.

I put the settings in according to the Excellent Mikeycal Meyers YouTube tutorials but the output, rendered from HD quality, was horrendously pixelated. I updated the settings according to the last 2,79 update video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CrpWJZsZpBk&index=31&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4

But now I do not seem to get an output file at all, any thoughts please?

[Render settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzO6t.png)
[File without extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOdoW.png)